# Is a headless CMS suitable for an interactive learning app?

Tags: database-design, content-management-system, strapi, directus, headless-cms

I would like to create an interactive learning app.
The app contains several modules and each module contains multiple excercises. Each of these excercises could contain a different amount of text, open-ended questions, multiple choice questions, and so on.
The answers for each user should be stored and referenced to the question (e.g. user A answered "xy" to question 3 of excercise 1).

I want to use a headless CMS to edit, store and maintain the content.
Since I need to store the answers, I will store them in an extra table. To implement this, each question and also each excercise and module should have an ID.

Is it feasible (and best practice) to implement this with a headless cms like Strapi, Directus or something similar?

Comment: I don't see why Strapi cannot be used on this example. It has a very complete set of tools related to APIs Restful and GraphQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely! Headless CMS like Directus offer a great way to manage content, data, and assets for any data-driven applications. Directus has the added benefit of "mirroring" your SQL database, so you can install it on an existing dataset (if you already have one), or make direct SQL queries, as needed.